# App screenshots not being shown in AppStore

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, app-store

I has recently submitted my iPhone app to App Store , which is compatible with iPhone 3GS and above and is optimised for iPhone 5. While submitting, I had added 1 screen shot for 4 inch screen and 5 screenshots for 3.5 inch screen. You can refer the picture below to get a better idea about the the list of images that i had added:

[image]

The issue is, 
while accessing appstore through any mobile device , I can see all the screenshots for my app, but when i access appstore from Computer, only the 4 inch retina display screen shots are visible!

has anyone faced the same issue before?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually it's because on below reason:

in iTunes of Computer/Mac, it will show iPhone5 & iPad devices (not iPhone4). Because iPhone5 is latest.

Now, when you will open your app in physical device, let's say iPhone4, then it will show iPhone4 screens.

Same, if you will open your app in iPad then it will show iPad screens.

Hope you got the point.

Cheers.

Comment: is there any way I can make is possible to view both the screenshots while am viewing from iphone?

Comment: No, actually it's apple default configuration. It's simple that, some apps are specific to iPhone only (calling app). And when you try to open the app with iPod, then you can not open the app in iPod, because you can't call from iPod. Got it.

Comment: so as per you comment, if i access appstore from **iPhone 5**, which screenshot will be visible?

Comment: so is there any option while submission, that I could make it possible to view both size screenshots from mac appstore?

Comment: So, at a time, you can view one type of screenshots.

Answer (score 2):

iTunes shows the latest device's screenshots.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it's correct.

By default Apple show screenshot of devices which are latest on Market.

So, as iPhone 5 is latest on Market, it shows screenshot of iPhone 5 only on iTunes of computer.

If you see same from your device, screenshots of your device will be shows respectively.

Hope this info helps you..

Comment: But why Do I see it when checking from iphone appstore..and not while am on mac appstore?

Comment: Reason is very simple, iPhone 4s people should see screenshots of iPhone 4s only, as users should look how application looks like in their device

Comment: For ex. I have game app and have iPhone 4s, I should see same device screenshots, as larger height screenshots for me are of no use, I cannot actually guess how that application will look like..

Comment: so is there any option while submission, that I could make it possible to view both size screenshots from mac appstore?

Comment: why you removed your comment?

Answer (score 1):

By default Apple show screenshot of devices which are latest on Market.

If your don't want to show **4 inch retina display screen shots** then just remove this from **itunesconnect** , only submit **3.5-Inch Retina Display Screenshots**

Comment: recently i submitted my application with out submitting iPhone 5 screenshots, check this link https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/whats-your-bmi/id595331418?ls=1&mt=8